# How can i dynamically call LoadLibraryA directly form Assembly (x86)?

Tags: assembly, x86, call, loadlibrary

How can i dynamically call LoadLibraryA directly from assembly (x86)? Currently LoadLibraryA is located at 0x76fc57c0 in my memory. I could statically call LoadLibraryA using:

```
mov eax, 76fc57c0h
call eax
```

But then with reboots/ASLR in place this is of course not stable. Is there a dynamic way to determine the memory address from LoadLibraryA?

Comment: Of course. You would do this by including the necessary header/include file in your source code, and linking against `kernel32.lib` when building your program. This will create a dependency to `LoadLibraryA` in `kernel32.dll`, which will be resolved by the dynamic linker when your EXE/DLL is loaded.

Comment: you need declare `extern __imp__LoadLibraryW@4:DWORD` and `call __imp__LoadLibraryW@4` and add *kernel32.lib* to linker input

Comment: @RbMm: thanks, that worked for me!!